# How much information exists about the former Prince of Chicago?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, vampire-the-requiem

Maxwell Clark is the current Prince of Chicago after the previous Prince mysteriously vanished  from the city. The former matron of Chicago is mentioned in the nWoD book, but nothing really about her rule, personality, or who she was aligned with (I believe she was a Carthian but I can not remember).

Is there any definitive information about the former leader that might be needed if she say, showed back up one evening?

Comment: I don't have a copy handy, but the information might be in the giant **World of Darkness: Chicago** crossover book.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is indeed a fair amount of information about "the Matriarch" in [WoD: Chicago](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/3073/World-of-Darkness%3a-Chicago).  I won't quote all of it, but perhaps I can hit some of the important points:

- Her name is Jaqueline Edens, and you are right that she is a Carthian.
- She was the child of an elite family of bankers and politicians.
- She ruled with an egalitarian politic from 1969-1986 (the shortest stint of any Chicago Prince).
- Her rule was one of freedom and respect for the responsibility of common kindred, but pretty much only the Carthians were happy with it.  When she was deposed in 1986, she had opponents at every angle who felt that more top-down control was necessary.
- Edens was partially brought down from the inside by her "chief information-gatherer," Norris Kleinspiegel, who was secretly working for Maxwell in spite of the broad power Edens had bestowed on him.
- She disappeared after the coup and there is no definitive word on her whereabouts.  She is probably hiding out in the Undercity in torpor.

There are some additional specifics in the book, but hopefully that's enough to give you a nice picture.

Past the canon, there is also some fan-created content related to Edens out there.  Pretty much all of the good stuff is from the [Fabula Rasa](http://www.fabula-rasa.net/wiki/Main_Page) game, which features her as a prominent character:

- A [stat block and some characterization](http://www.fabula-rasa.net/wiki/Jaqueline_Edens).
- A [chat log](http://www.fabula-rasa.net/wiki/Logs%3aThe_Matriarch%27s_Rescue) during which the characters rescue Edens from torpor.
- A [timeline](http://www.fabula-rasa.net/wiki/Vampire%3a_Timeline) noting the important events involving the Matriarch.